# How many types of pre- processing techniques have in machine learning before split the train and test the dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, data-processing

How many types of different pre-processing techniques are exists in machine learning for data-sets.  I  want to define the  general template that help me in pre-processing on the different problem.

I done some operation on image classification like resize, rgb2grayscale, find out dummy images, process on two images and that result added in the data-set.

My goal to optimise the data-set with the different techniques.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `python-3.x` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of pre-processing techniques, which to use depends upon your dataset. Some of the techniques are:

- **Data Cleaning:** Data is cleansed through processes such as filling in missing values, smoothing the noisy data, or resolving the inconsistencies in the data.
- **Data Integration:** Data with different representations are put together and conflicts within the data are resolved.
- **Data Transformation:** Data is normalized, aggregated and generalized.
- **Data Reduction:** This step aims to present a reduced representation of the data in a data warehouse.
- **Data Discretization:** Involves the reduction of a number of values of a continuous attribute by dividing the range of attribute intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-processing is a very broad term and more importantly what one might consider as pre-processing depends heavily on what you want to do with the data -for example cropping out the faces for a face recognition task- and the data itself since  you might have a dataset that would need a very specific kind of pre-processing - e.g. deleting watermarks from a corner of image.

That being said, [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-pre-processing-c1aec0be3edf) is a useful guide I found. I think you have already done most of what would be considered as general pre-processing.